# server side fetch in mounted () vuejs is not rendering

Tags: vue.js

```
async mounted () {
    if (!this.isUserLoggedIn) {
      return
    }
    console.log('SongMetadata - beforeMount')
    console.log('songId: ', this.$store.state.route.params.songId)
    console.log('userId', this.$store.state.user.id)
    console.log('isBookmarked: ', this.isBookmarked)
    let bookmark = {}
    try {
      bookmark = (BookmarksService.index({
        songId: this.$store.state.route.params.songId,
        userId: this.$store.state.user.id
      })).data
      console.log('Returning bookmark: ', bookmark)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    if (bookmark.length === 0) {
      this.isBookmarked = false
    } else {
      this.isBookmarked = true
    }
    console.log('isBookmarked: ', this.isBookmarked)
  },
```

---

Vue does not render the updated value of this.isBookmarked. It stops right before the **await BookmarksService function**. Any thoughts how I can ask VueJS to wait for the server side to complete before rendering can start. Thanks

Comment: It shouldn't be `(await BookmarksService.index(...`?

Comment: See Vue Forum [Best practice for Displaying async loaded data](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/best-practice-for-displaying-async-loaded-data/17932)

Comment: Thanks @andref94, actually my function does start with await. I missed saying it